# How to set RPO and RTO for Azure VM

Tags: azure

My requirement is "Disaster Recovery (24 hours RPO and RTO) for AZUR VM". How can I set 24hrs RPO and RTO with Azure ASR?

Note: it's not perfectly defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-overview

There is a lot of confusion due to lack of data that how to set RPO and RTO in Azure.

If someone could share with an example would be great help.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Add some code and show us what you have tried.